# Merge polygons in CartoDB?

Tags: polygon, carto

I created this map in cartodb: http://cdb.io/1xBj4Xo

Now I have to merge some of the districts to a bigger district. Is it possible to do this in Cartodb? Using a SQL query for instance?

I can also provide a .csv-file: http://tradukt.ch/owncloud/public.php?service=files&t=2fe413428dd38103705fa4191236b8fc

Screenshot of the table:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your CSV,

**Tablename**: Wahlkreise
**Column** containing value to union on: wahlkreis
**Other Columns** use an aggregate function to grab one of the values (all of them are the same for each district / wahlkreis

In the SQL window in CartoDB, type:

```
   SELECT   

wahlkreis  
, cartodb_id  
, max(strong_party) as strong_party  
, max(einwohner) as einwohner  
, max(mandate) as mandate  
, max(kandidaten) as kandidaten  
, max(frauen) as frauen  
, max(maenner) as maenner  
, max(fdp) as fdp  
, max(svp) as svp  
, max(sp) as sp  
, max(glp) as glp  
, max(gruene) as gruene  
, max(evp) as evp  
, max(cvp) as cvp  
, max(bdp) as bdp  

, st_union(the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator      


FROM wahlkreise_bl_1

group by wahlkreis, wahlkreise_bl_1.cartodb_id
```

At this point, map interaction must be enabled by adding the CartoDB_id to the SQL and GROUP BY clause, but there seems to be a bug that removes the st_union function from working properly (I will keep digging in).

The workflow instead could be to simply use the 'create table from query' option to write your query to a new file, and you can take advantage of the full interactivity based on your SQL processing.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to do it. What would districtName and districtID be? If you clone the map, you can see several communities. I need like four or five communities to become a larger district. That would be gmdnr (column) and 2761, 2762 and 2763 (rows). So that I can have a larger district to manipulate it further (color, popup etc.)

Comment: can you post a screen grab of the table portion of your data? The CSV isn't entirely necessary...

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: @Felix I updated my answer, but you might want to share your CSV if possible...

Comment: awesome, that works! I just had to adapt the table name! Thanks a lot!

Comment: the only problem I have know, that I only have the new polygons without the other information, can I add another query or how can I get all my other information?

Comment: I added a link to the csv-file

Answer (score 0):

An another solution for a basic use (just merge all polygons):

```
Select ST_Union(the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator      
FROM Tablename
group by cartodb_id
```