# Dissolve/merge polygons using ST_Union in CARTO

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, dissolve, union

I am attempting to dissolve the boundaries between several polygons using a common attribute within a column in CARTO and the `ST_Union` function.

In my scenario, I have created a table for all US Zip Codes, & have given each Zip Code a value within a column called `area_zip_r`. I would like to dissolve/merge the polygon boundaries for all zip codes that share a common "area_zip_r" value, creating a single polygon for each value within "area_zip_r".

After some initial research and the help of [this Stackexchange article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128310/merge-polygons-in-cartodb?rq=1) I have come up with the following command which does dissolve/merge the polygons, but also leaves gaps of data for an unknown reason.

```
SELECT 
  cartodb_id, 
  area_zip_r,
  ST_union(the_geom_webmercator) as the_geom_webmercator
FROM 
  {table_name}
GROUP BY 
  area_zip_r, 
  cartodb_id
```

Results: Many of the `area_zip_r` values are seen in the output with the desired effects, but I only see a small percent of the `area_zip_r` values I expect to see. I am returned with approximately 500 unique `area_zip_r` values when I expect 2000. This is verified when mapping the results. I've attached photographs to show the area my original table covers, and the results of my `ST_Union` command.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Un-stylized map of all US Zip Codes with "area_zip_r" value]

[image: Results of ST_Union showing gaps in data]

Comment: Your query looks OK to me. Could you share the link to the dataset? My guess is that you have invalid geometries.

Comment: @ramiroaznar thanks for the input. I cleared the command so you can see the original data. https://dougdement.carto.com/dataset/zip_rollup_w_modulus_id_copy_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have tested, it looks like the problem could be the `cartodb_id`. Follow these steps, and you should get the union right:

- First, I recommend applying this query in the dataset view:

```
SELECT 
  max(cartodb_id) as cartodb_id, 
  area_zip_r, 
  ST_union(the_geom) as the_geom
FROM 
  zip_rollup_w_modulus_id_copy_1
GROUP BY 
  area_zip_r
```

- Secondly, create a new dataset from the query.
- If you count the number of features, the result will be the expected: `2715`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Was the problem simply the missing max command in front of the cartodb_id & including the cartodb_id in the group by clause? or something to do with invalid geometries?